# What does leverage lower than 1 means for ETFs

Tags: trading, etf, interactive-brokers, leverage

I've recently noticed in my IB terminal that many ETFs have leverage lower than 1. I understand that some ETFs have leverage higher than 1 for example `TQQQ` because they mainly use derivatives but I don't understand what's the reason for leverage lower than 1.

[image]

Comment: It probably means that a fraction of the capital is held in cash, instead of being invested.

Comment: `ARKW` allocates 99% of funds in stocks [link](http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=ARKW&region=usa&culture=en-US&ops=&cur=USD&productcode=COM) and only 0.5% of funds in cash on short position.

Comment: If you hover your mouse pointer over the word LVRG it should display a 1 sentence description of what that column represents. If it doesn't or it is not clear you should contact IB.

Comment: Knowing how careful IB is in covering its a**, I will *guess* that this how much margin IB will allow you  to use when you buy this security. LVRG 1 is normal, 0.3 means you are allowed very little margin (30% of normal) and must put up the rest in cash to buy ARKK.

Comment: If you do what I told you, you will see "Leverage Debt divided by common equity. For more AltaVista ETF research information, right click on an ETF select Analytical Tools and then select ETF Term Sheet".